# jQuery animate circle

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to animate a circle with Jquery:

The circle will be a round picture (let's say a ball) that will turn around itself 360 degrees.

How can I do it without flash?

It should stay in the same place, but will only rotate (wander around)

Comment: 360 degrees in what orientation? Is it an image you want to animate? Why not make a gif?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/transform

Comment: Just to make clear, around which axis will the ball be rotating?

Comment: it could be a gif. orientation like the clock. But the picture will be full from the first moment, but will rotate none stop in a slow pace

Comment: https://github.com/clearideaz/jQuery.rotate

Comment: @ZsoltSchäfer it should be around its main axis. It should stay in the same place all the time

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you actually want, but assuming you want it to rotate on it's own axis, have a look at this code I just whipped up:

http://jsfiddle.net/RpjuD/2/

This only works in browsers with animation support, but nowadays that's really only IE. IE10 has support.

To get a rotation animation in older browsers, you are kind of stuck - there aren't many options short of using an animated gif. IE does support a rotation property, but it's very limited.

You could use something like https://github.com/clearideaz/jQuery.rotate/blob/master/jrotate.plugin.js to get it working everywhere, but to be honest, usually the CPU cost for users stuck on old browsers with old hardware isn't worth it.

Comment: It will only work in IE10, Firefox supports this fine in the latest version.

Comment: Try the link again - I made a typo!

Comment: Well, I've tested it and it is fine. :)

Answer (score 0):

You will only be able to rotate an element if the browser is CSS3 compatible (minus other hacks such as this http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2009/12/colorful-clock-jquery-css/demo.html), in which case you should set a timing function to adjust the following CSS:

```
-moz-transform:rotate(120deg);
-webkit-transform:rotate(120deg);
-o-transform:rotate(120deg);
```

see this:

http://davidwalsh.name/css-transform-rotate

Comment: Hi! I tried your example in chrome and it doesn't display it there. Isn't it the newest browser?

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS3 as pointed out by the others, or use SVG (e.g. http://raphaeljs.com/) or Canvas.

Answer (score 0):

For CSS3 transitions and transforms, you can better use this nice jQuery plugin: http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/

Answer (score -1):

Lea Verou posted a solution using css3
 http://lea.verou.me/2012/02/moving-an-element-along-a-circle/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+leaverou+%28Lea+Verou%29&utm_content=Netvibes

Comment: This one is not good - since the image is not in the place all the time. It should be in the same place, only rotating around it.